# Which moves are triggered by the passage of in-game or real time?

Tags: time, masks-a-new-generation

In *MASKS: A new Generation*, there are a number of moves that trigger "whenever time passes." There are also rules that make moves trigger at the end of a scene, or the end of a session. I'm making a notecard to remind myself what all of them are, for use while GMing.

**What is the complete list of these moves?**

Answer (score 7):

Here is my own list so far (marked as Community Wiki so that it can take additive edits easily)

#### Whenever Time Passes

- The GM restocks the Team pool with with one Team token.
- The Janus (if in play) rolls for Secret Identity
- The Reformed (if in play) rolls for Friends in Low Places
- The Legacy (if in play) rolls for Legacy

#### At the end of a scene

- If a hero took the specified actions to clear their conditions, clear them.
- The Nova (if in play) loses all Burn.
- All Hold is cleared, unless otherwise specified.

#### At the end of a session

- The End of Session move triggers.
- The Doomed, if they made progress toward defeating their Nemesis, marks potential, otherwise marks doom track.
- The Brain, if they took steps to atone for their shame, marks potential, otherwise gives influence to a teammate.